# How to get the location(LatLng/Name) in a google map at the centre of map

Tags: android, google-maps

Guys I'm implementing google maps in my android app and instread of creating a marker i've placed a marker image in the middle of map. Now I want that whenever user drags the map i get the location at the centre of the map(where i've placed my image look like a marker).

My map activity is :

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
TextView Title;
FrameLayout goback;
Location myLocation;
LocationManager locationManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

    //try
    Title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.map_title);
    Title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Header"));
    goback=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
  //  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();


        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {



}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));
    CameraPosition ll=mMap.getCameraPosition();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ll,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

please help me in doing so, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys, I'm going to try these things and will respond back soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can get referance of your map container, and calculate center point by dividing 2 width and height.

```
View containerView=findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);

LatLng centerPoint=   this.map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(((int)containerView.getWidth/2),((int)(containerView.getHeight/2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the center this way:

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

where mMap is the GoogleMap instance from your activity. This will return a LatLng object which basically represents the center of the map. Note that the GeoPoint class is not anymore available.

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html

target is "The location that the camera is pointing at." (tested it with the sample code and it worked ok for me)

Let me know if this helped you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
MapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y)
```

Where x is half your map width and y is half the height. This should return you a coordinates object which in turn will give you your longitude and latitude of the center of your map

More information on it can be seen [here](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/get-the-coordinates-latitude-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for the resopnse but won't it change when the app runs on some other resolution device?

Comment: Not if you use the width and height of the container holding the map. The map will scale with the device